# Bootstrap tab with custom border

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on wizard where the header is the one showed at following picture. I'm using Bootstrap-4 tabs components and :after pseudo element approach on li element, but I don't know how to get the background with two color.

Desired result

[image]

HTML snippet

```
<ul class="nav classic-tabs nav-justified white" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link waves-light active" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel61" role="tab"> Frete</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link waves-light" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel62" role="tab"> Pagamento</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link waves-light" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel63" role="tab"> Revise e Confirme</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS snippet

```
&:after {
    content: '';
    border-right: 1px solid #666666;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
```

Actual result

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably style the actual tabs. Styling pseudo-elements brings in a level of complication that you don't want to deal with.

Here I'm skewing the tabs right, then adding an inner span element to skew the text back to vertical.

I'm using pseudo:before to create the 90-degree left side to the first tab. You could do the same for the final tab. It may be tricky to get the shadows and borders to work out, but I think it's feasible.

```
.nav-tabs .nav-item {
  transform: skew(-22.5deg);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

li.nav-item:first-child::before {
  content: '';
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: skew(22.5deg);
  top: 1px;
  left: -8px;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-item a span {
  transform: skew(22.5deg);
  display: inline-block;
}

<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab"><span>Home</span></a>
</li>
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/vjL6r8rj/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here a version based on Isherwood answer that fixes the first and last tab border issue. I know that isn't the most eficient solution but worked well.

Result
[image]

HTML code

```
<div class="tabs-wrapper z-depth-1">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active first" data-toggle="tab" href="#frete" role="tab"><span>Frete</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#pagamento" role="tab"><span>Pagamento</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link last" data-toggle="tab" href="#confirmacao" role="tab"><span>Revise e Confirme</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS code (SASS)

```
.tabs-wrapper {
    margin-top: 5rem;

    .nav {
      background-color: $cinza;
      padding: 0;

      .nav-item {
        transform: skew(-22.5deg);
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);

        .nav-link {
          @include transition(all 1s);
          color: $gray-500;
          background-color: $cinza;

          span {
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            transform: skew(22.5deg);
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 1rem 0;
          }

          &.active {
            @include transition(all 1s);
            background-color: #fff;
            color: $gray-900;
            font-weight: 700;
          }

          &.first {
            &:before {
              @include transition(all 1s);
              position: absolute;
              content: '';
              background: $cinza;
              height: 100%;
              width: 2rem;
              top: 0;
              left: -1rem;
              transform: skew(22.5deg);
            }

            &.active {
              &:before {
                @include transition(all 1s);
                background: #fff;
              }
            }
          }

          &.last {
            &:before {
              @include transition(all 1s);
              position: absolute;
              content: '';
              background: $cinza;
              height: 100%;
              width: 2rem;
              top: 0;
              right: -1rem;
              transform: skew(22.5deg);
            }

            &.active {
              &:before {
                @include transition(all 1s);
                background: #fff;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```